# Protractor Unable to execute test cases in Chome using webdriver-manager

Tags: protractor

Protractor is unable to start test cases in chrome browser using webdriver-manager.

I followed the instructions given here https://www.protractortest.org/#/
and faced the below error.

```
debarnab@debarnab-Aspire-A515-51G:~/ProtractorConnectionTesting$ protractor conf.js
[19:33:57] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:33:57] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[19:33:57] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'debarnab-Aspire-A515-51G', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[19:33:57] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'debarnab-Aspire-A515-51G', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[19:33:57] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

**conf.ts file**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

**spec file**

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

I am using Ubutu machine and trying to run a basic scenario. Selenium Server seems to be up and running in http://localhost:4444/, as mentioned. Can any one please suggest ?

Comment: selenium server up. Do you have GPU on your UBUNTU? Try to run headless chrome

Answer (score 0):

Make your config as below

```
exports.config = {
      directConnect: true,

      // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
      },

      // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
      framework: 'jasmine',

      // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
      // protractor is called.
      specs: ['example_spec.js'],

      // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
      }
    };
```

Run `npm i webdriver-manager` & `webdriver-manager update` from your project folder.

if you get `No Update config found` error when trying to run the test run `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

Now run your test

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642913/10836734) it appears that you can add `--disable-dev-shm-usage` when running on Linux machines to resolve this issue.

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: { args: ["--disable-dev-shm-usage"] },
    },    
};
```

Can you give this a try and let me know if it works? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running your job using the following chrome arg:

```
 --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="no-sandbox"
```